# .find() is not a function Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was working on a project, having an issue with my Schema queries. When I hit my endpoints, I get the error `TypeError: Menu.find is not a function`

Error

```
TypeError: Menu.find is not a function
    at index (D:\Projects\Pizzaa Ordering App\app\http\controllers\homeController.js:6:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Pizzaa Ordering App\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Projects\Pizzaa Ordering App\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)........
```

and many Lines

My Server File:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const ejs = require('ejs') //Engine
const path = require('path')
const expressLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
    // Database
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


// Database Connection
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/pizza-test';
mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Database connected...');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Connection failed...');
});


// Assets
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Set template engine
app.use(expressLayout)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/resources/views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// Routes
require('./routes/web')(app)

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

web.js file // All routers

```
const homeController = require('../app/http/controllers/homeController')
const authController = require('../app/http/controllers/authController')
const cartController = require('../app/http/controllers/customers/cartController')

function initRoutes(app) {
    app.get('/', homeController().index)

    app.get('/cart', cartController().index)

    app.get('/login', authController().login)

    app.get('/register', authController().register)
}

module.exports = initRoutes
```

homeControllerFile.js // Router code // req, res

```
const Menu = require('../../models/menu')

function homeController() {
    return {
        index(req, res) {
            Menu.find().then((pizzas) => {
                console.log(pizzas);
                return res.render('home', { pizzas: pizzas });
            })
        }
    }
}

module.exports = homeController
```

my menu.js file // from where Menu Export

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const menuSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    size: { type: String, required: true }
});


mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('Menu', menuSchema)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo replace `mongoose.exports` with `module.exports`

Comment: Wowww.. Thank you so much I am trying to resolve this from past 1 hour. 

Comment: Then it's a good thing that you posted here!